# Erlang.mk + boss_db: minimal working example

Tags: erlang, chicagoboss

I am unable to find any existing examples of using Erlang.mk as a build system with boss_db.

When I bootstrap Erlang.mk project, and just add boss_db as
`DEPS += boss_db`
and run `make run`, Erlang prints that boss_db application started. But when I try to run `boss_db:start([SomeOptions])`, suddenly, Erlang prints out error like `exited with reason: call to undefined function aleppo:process_tokens`. If I manually add `aleppo` to Makefile, it will work (but to actually USE boss_db I also have to add like `poolboy`, which is already listed in boss_db dependencies).

I want to request a minimal working example of Erlang.mk + boss_db, because documentation really lacks it, and I dont want to use entire ChicagoBoss for my needs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there in particular reason why it has to be erlang.mk? rebar3 I would say is the community standard.

Comment: @starbelly no, actually. I started from Cowboy bootstrap guide, and it uses erlang.mk. If you think that it makes sense to create rebar3 project, and add cowboy as dependency, I would follow that way (and I hope it will solve my main issue).

Comment: I see. Well, I honestly would recommend sumo_db over boss_db. I had too much trouble getting barely going with this stand-alone and that may be because it was never intended to work stand alone. It's also not going to work very well with recent version of erlang. Right off the bat it wants parametrized module attributes and that's no longer supported. Anyway, check out sumo_db : https://github.com/inaka/sumo_db

Comment: @starbelly I will take a look at this project. Thank you very much, it is very hard to find any information on ORM's for Erlang this days.